# Vector components on a pyramid (Validity check)

Tags: geometry, vectors

Apologies for asking something like this, but I have been asked a high school question about vectors. This is a question asked in a standard high school in UK so I expect the solution to be straightforward. However, I believe it is not possible to solve the question with given information. I know this may not be an appropriate question to be asked here, but may I ask if you could verify my conclusion about the question? Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: From the diagram one would guess that the projection of $T$ onto the base is the midpoint of $PR$, but that is impossible with the given components.

Answer (score 0):

I could've left this as a comment but it was gonna be a long comment.

There is definitely not enough information here. Let me not use your data, as my pint can be made for a much simpler setup. Suppose
$$
\vec{SP}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
2\\
0
\end{pmatrix}, \qquad
\vec{ST}=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
now given  $-\pi/4< \alpha<\pi/4$, define
$$
\vec{SR}=2(\cos \alpha +\sin \alpha) \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \alpha\\
0\\
\sin \alpha
\end{pmatrix}
$$
you can check easily that for any such choice of $\alpha$ the above data determines a pyramid with rectangular base. So unless one knows, at least, the length $|\vec{SR}|$, there is no sense in asking what $\vec{PR}$ is.

Comment: Thanks! I also reached a similar conclusion in a different manner, but I wanted a second opinion in case if I missed something.